# Block specific file out of static directory with nginx

Tags: nginx, source-maps

I have a statically served React application with Nginx.

```
worker_processes  1;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    sendfile        on;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    server {
        listen       3000;
        server_name  localhost;

        root /usr/share/nginx/html;

        location ^~ /static/ {
            root /usr/share/nginx/html/;
        }

        location / {
            try_files $uri /index.html;
            index  index.html;
        }

        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }

    }
}
```

During build (with Vite) we produce source maps which are served in development.
For specific environments (`stage.*` and `app.*` but not `dev.*`) I would like to **not** serve the source maps.
I have no option to not build source maps for these environments in the first place, because we migrate entire builds between environments.
I want to use Nginx to not serve `*.map` files out of `/static` for these environments.
How would I do that?

Comment: Try adding `location ~* \.map$ { return 403; }` within the `location ^~ /static/` block.

Comment: @RichardSmith thank you, but how do I make this domain-dependant? I want this line to apply to all domains OTHER than `dev.domain.com`